# React query paginated query not enabling next button as per example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have followed this example:

https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/guides/paginated-queries

However, when I have tried doing it myself, the next button is always disabled? so I can't click next. my code is below:

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-kju94g?file=index.tsx)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import axios from 'axios';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider} from 'react-query';

const App: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const queryKey = 'getData';
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1)

  const getDataFunction = async (page): Promise<any> => {
    const response = await axios
      .get(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=10&_page=${page}`
      )
      .then((res) => res.data);
    return response;
  };

  const {
    data: result,
    isFetching,
    status,
    error,
    refetch,
    isPreviousData,
  }: any = useQuery([queryKey, page], () => getDataFunction(page), {
    keepPreviousData : true,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
  });

  return (
    <div className="Container" >
      <button onClick={refetch}>Refetch query</button>
      {status === 'error' && <div className="mt-5">{error.message}</div>}
      {isFetching ? (
        <div className="mt-5">Loading data ...</div>
      ) : (
        <div style={{height: 'auto', border: '1px solid', padding: '15px', margin: '10px 0px 10px 0px'}}>
          {status === 'success' && (
            <div>
              <p>
                {result?.map((inner, index) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={index}>
                      <p>
                        {inner?.id}
                        <br />
                        <strong>{inner?.title}</strong> <br />
                        {inner?.body}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </p>
              <p>{result?.title}</p>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
            <span>Current Page: {page}</span>
       <button
         onClick={() => setPage(old => Math.max(old - 1, 0))}
         disabled={page === 1}
       >
         Previous Page
       </button>{' '}
       <button
         onClick={() => {
           if (!isPreviousData && result?.hasMore) {
             setPage(old => old + 1)
           }
         }}
         // Disable the Next Page button until we know a next page is available
         disabled={isPreviousData || !result?.hasMore}
       >
         Next Page
       </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

render(
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <App />
  </QueryClientProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Any idea's?

Comment: what happens if you simplify the disabled property? just for testing, set disabled=false maybe there is an issue with your conditions? isPreviousData || !result?.hasMore try using only one or the other, and try to invert the bool using '!', like your second condition.  the button draws, so it should be a logic issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In their example the response from the server contained `hasMore` flag, in your case you don't have it, you have just set of data.
So the only way you could check if the next page is available is by checking if `length` of the data returned to you is equals page size (10 in your case). It is not perfect, because it might be that the last available page contains 10 items (in your case it means that total is 100 or 10 or 20 and so on...), so the next page will have 0, but it is the only thing you can do here, if, of course you don't know total in advance.

So basically you need

`const hasNext = result?.length == 10;`

And then use it

```
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      if (!isPreviousData && hasNext) {
        setPage((old) => old + 1);
      }
    }}
    // Disable the Next Page button until we know a next page is available
    disabled={!hasNext}
  >
    Next Page
  </button>
```

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ggyyg8?file=index.tsx

Comment: Thanks, however in your stackblitz example, why can you click on 1 page past the last results page?

Comment: @sole I’ve explained it - because I don’t know Total number and there is no way you or I could know that the last page also has exactly 10 items, if there were 99 items - you wouldn’t be able to click, but it just so happens that right now API returns exactly 100 items. See the point? If you are sure that there will always be 100 - then you can modify my code, if are not sure - that’s the best you can get basically, or you need other API to get you total count

Answer (score 2):

`hasMore` is not a value from `react-query`, it should be returned from your server to tell your frontend that you have more data in the next page.

Your example API does not return anything in `result.hasMore`, that is why the button has remained disabled.

I assume typicode returns a max of 100 items, so you can do this to use the limit and page number as a reference

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import axios from 'axios';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider} from 'react-query';

const App: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const queryKey = 'getData';
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1)
  const [limit] = React.useState(10)

  const getDataFunction = async (page): Promise<any> => {
    const response = await axios
      .get(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=${limit}&_page=${page}`
      )
      .then((res) => res.data);
    return response;
  };

  const {
    data: result,
    isFetching,
    status,
    error,
    refetch,
    isPreviousData,
  }: any = useQuery([queryKey, page], () => getDataFunction(page), {
    keepPreviousData : true,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
  });

  return (
    <div className="Container" >
      <button onClick={refetch}>Refetch query</button>
      {status === 'error' && <div className="mt-5">{error.message}</div>}
      {isFetching ? (
        <div className="mt-5">Loading data ...</div>
      ) : (
        <div style={{height: 'auto', border: '1px solid', padding: '15px', margin: '10px 0px 10px 0px'}}>
          {status === 'success' && (
            <div>
              <p>
                {result?.map((inner, index) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={index}>
                      <p>
                        {inner?.id}
                        <br />
                        <strong>{inner?.title}</strong> <br />
                        {inner?.body}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </p>
              <p>{result?.title}</p>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
            <span>Current Page: {page}</span>
       <button
         onClick={() => setPage(old => Math.max(old - 1, 0))}
         disabled={page === 1}
       >
         Previous Page
       </button>{' '}
       <button
         onClick={() => {
           if (!isPreviousData && (page * limit) < 100) {
             setPage(old => old + 1)
           }
         }}
         // Disable the Next Page button until we know a next page is available
         disabled={isPreviousData || (page * limit) >= 100}
       >
         Next Page
       </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

render(
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <App />
  </QueryClientProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```